# Does the magnesium 2+ ion prefer tetrahedral or octahedral coordination?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

In organic chemistry I was told that the magnesium ion which is part of Grignard reagents is coordinated to several ether molecules. The overall structure around the magnesium is *tetrahedral*, which implies that *two* ether molecules have coordinated to the magnesium center. The professor said something about fulfilling magnesium ion's octet with this configuration.

In inorganic chemistry and biochemistry however I learned about hexacoordinated magnesium - i.e. $\ce{Mg(H2O)6}$. Magnesium ion tends to form octahedral complexes; this implies a coordination number of 6.

So -

1. Does magnesium ion adopt both these configurations? Can it be found as part of tetrahedral and octahedral complexes?
2. Which is preferred? I suspect this answer depends on a variety of factors.

Comment: Have a look at "ligand-field theory"...

Comment: You have to make a clear distinction between octet (electron configuration) and octahedral (coordination geometry).

Answer (score 2):

Magnesium bonded to most purely nonmetallic elements is predominantly ionic or ion/dipole, even hydrogen with its low electronegativity (but poor covalent overlap with the rather diffuse magnesium valence orbitals). So the "octet rule" or "valence electron count" applies less than the balance between magnesium being attracted to negative charges against steric effects/repulsions between like charges. That balance, at least with magnesium, is usually struck with octahedral coordination.

Two compounds where magnesium shows different coordination geometry:

**Magnesium diboride, $\ce{MgB2}$.** In this moderately high temperature superconductor ($T_c = 39$ K) the boron is organized into graphene-like sheets, which effectively fixes the coordination geometry as hexagonal-prismatic. Each magnesium ion is coordinated to a hexagonal space between boron atoms on each surrounding graphene-like sheet. The bonding orbitals of the graphene-like sheets are at lower energy than isolated boron atomic orbitals, so the boron is effectively more electronegative and the magnesium-boron bonding here is predominantly ionic.

**Magnesium silicide, $\ce{Mg2Si}$.** This narrow-gap semiconductor, along with its counterparts having heavier G14 elements in place of silicon, has drawn interest for thermoelectric applications. Here the magnesium is tetrahedrally coordinated, in part because this already corresponds to a high coordination number (eight, in an antifluorite structure) for the silicon. The high coordination number on silicon again implies enhanced ionic character (silicon would form only four bonds in a purely covalent mode), so steric factors related to the silicon coordination apparently play more role in limiting the magnesium coordination than covalent bonding "rules".